# JSON array to and from MySql. Saving and Looping

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

```
<?
$cl = $row["saved_json_string_column"];
?>
```

expecting this output from the db query to create a new array

```
//cl = '[{"ifeid":1,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"2"},{"ifeid":2,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"5"}]';   
    cl = '<? echo $cl;?>';
```

// I would like to start with the saved 'cl' array and push new items to it.
    skptoQarry = new Array();

//javascript function loop (not shown) generates vars and pushes to new array.

```
thisItem_eid = 1;
yes_no_is_this = 'No';
SkipToTartgetEID = 5;

var skptoQarry_temp = {
     "ifeid" : thisItem_eid,
     "ans" : yes_no_is_this,
     "type" : "SkipTo",
     "target" : SkipToTartgetEID
};          
skptoQarry.push(skptoQarry_temp);

cl = JSON.stringify(skptoQarry); //for ajax post to php for saving
```

//this is what is in saved the DB via ajax post

[{"ifeid":1,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"2"},{"ifeid":2,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"5"}]

//...but when PHP echos it out only this comes out: cl = "[,]"
// I think i'm saving it wrong or echoing the column data the wrong way.

//read text from mysql and append where needed.

```
cl = $.parseJSON(cl);

jQuery.each(cl, function (i) {
    jQuery.each(this, function (key, value) { 
        if (key == "ifeid") {
                $('div').append('if this id: '+value+'<br>');
        } else if (key == "ans") {
                $('div').append('is: '+value+'<br>');
        } else if (key == "type") {
                $('div').append('then: '+value+'<br>');
        } else if (key == "target") {
                $('div').append('this id: '+value+'<br><br>');
        }    
    });
});

function saveit(){
saved_logic_dialog = JSON.stringify(skptoQarry);
var posturl = "myurl?event=save&saved_logic_dialog="+saved_logic_dialog;
    jQuery.ajax({
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: posturl,
        success: function(data) {
        //messages and stuff 
        }
    });
}
```

//php

```
$loadvfsql = "SELECT `saved_logic_dialog` FROM `questions` WHERE `id` = '{$id}' ORDER BY `questions`.`question_order` ASC";

$loadv_result=mysql_query($loadvfsql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($loadv_result)){
$clc = $rows['current_logic_cont'];
$cl = $rows['saved_logic_dialog'];
//more stuff
}
```

Comment: Check your DB record. Is it really `[{"ifeid":1,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"2"},{"ifeid":2,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"5"}]` ? Also you need to decode what is posted to your php post file.

Comment: Saved in the DB record is: [{"ifeid":1,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"2"},{"ifeid":2,"ans":"Yes","type":"SkipTo","target":"5"}] 

I can't get it to echo it into a new array. I used JSON.stringify and sent to php post where it is not being decoded but is still being saved.

Comment: Try `cl = '<? echo json_encode($cl);?>';`

Comment: same result for cl "[,]"

Comment: It might be a mysqli logical error can you post your fetch logic ?

Comment: If you try that select against the database with the id you are using are you sure you are getting results ?

Comment: The query return the right result when in PHPmyAdmin but not in the while loop.

Comment: For starters I propose you remove that deprecated `mysql_query()` and switch to mysqli logic. [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (I imagine you are not using stone age php) It's just going to cause you problems in the future because they are going trash it.

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure your array of objects is properly encoded - jQuery will not encode the URL for you.

```
var posturl = "myurl?event=save&saved_logic_dialog=" + encodeURIComponent(saved_logic_dialog);
```

- When saving to DB - check for properly escaping the value (as it will certainly contain quotes);
- When echoing the value back into HTML - use `htmlspecialchars($cl)` to properly escape the symbols which might have special meaning in HTML.
- Before using the value in JavaScript - use `JSON.parse(cl)` to convert from String into Array.